# Como obtener paginacion en django?

Tags: django, python-requests

Utilizando Django.
tengo info sobre cantidad de paginacion en base de datos esta cantidad es ingresada por cada usuario y almacenada en bd.
 mi inquietud es:
¿ Como puedo paginar con la cantidad que tengo almacenada en bd ?, ejemplo que el 25 cambie por el numero que tengo en mi base de datos que tengo en base de datos

```js
class Datos(ListView):
    model = Datos
    template_name = 'Datos.html'
    paginate_by = 25
```

En mi modelo:

```js
class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    pagination = models.IntegerField(default=50)
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de poder modificarlo es modificar la variable `paginate_by` dentro de la función `get_context_data()` pero lo más recomentable es sobreescribir la funcion `get_queryset()` de esta forma:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def get_queryset(self,npagina=1):
    consulta = Datos.objects.all()
    paginacion = Paginator(consulta,'cantidad objetos')
    if len(paginacion.page(1)) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return paginacion.page(npagina)
```

Debes modificar tu get_context_data para obtener el resultado y pasarlo a tu template añadiendo esto:
    context['datos'] = self.get_queryset(npagina=self.request.GET.get('page'))

Y por último añade esto tu tamplate:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">
    {% if datos.has_previous %}
        <li>
            <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}">Anterior</a></span>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
        <li class="">
            <span>Página {{ page_obj.number }} de {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
        </li>
    {% if datos.has_next %}
        <li>
            <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}">Siguiente</a></span>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Puedes modificar la función de get_queryset a tu gusto, solo es un ejemplo para que puedas modificarlo de la forma que quieras

Comment: Gracias Amigo por tu aporte voy a ponerlo a prueba

Answer (score 0):

buenos dias espero esten bien, queria pedir ayuda ya que estoy en la misma situacion. En context['datos'], 'datos' que seria? Recien me estoy iniciando en Django por lo que no tengo muchas experiencia, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: hola si claro como estas como tienes tu view ?

Comment: Hola Edgardo, por favor no uses las respuestas para replicar a una pregunta ya hecha, mejor anímate a formular una nueva pregunta. Lee el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: perdon, ahi genere una pregunta nueva, muchas gracias